# ST Region Icon and Targeted Regions in Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, smarttarget

Experience Manager displays SmartTarget (ST) regions with a special icon. It also shows the [Regions for the page](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-66F1A938-22A7-401A-8C54-2CB700B1EF3E) to let you configure promotions in context as seen below.

[image: Target Regions in page info]

I believe XPM knows about the icon and Targeted Regions from the ST tag or control.

**Does XPM detect ST regions client side (similar to XPM-enabled CPs and fields)?**

In setups without ST tags/controls (like with [DD4T](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dd4t-and-sdl-smarttarget-2014-integration)), I've seen targetted promotions. How would the technical team also show:

- Targeted Regions in the info section for the page?
- The ST icon

Is there anything else we should implement when not using the ST tags/controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, XPM detects the SmartTarget regions client side. The ST XPM features are triggered by the `<!-- Start Query: -->` tag. Depending on the content of this tag the promotion/fallback content bullseye on the ST region and Targeted Regions section in the context menu will be shown.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeroen. Do you know of an example of that format and/or have you seen a DD4T project generate this with a custom tag/control?

Comment: The `ResultSet.GetExperienceManagerMarkup` method of the SmartTarget API will generate this markup for you.